# Single Datagridview Master-Details, no error but only shows "(Collection)"

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

I am using SQLite and I would like to use Master-Detail in a single DataGridView.  No error return, I check the Master Table ("ASM") and the Details Table ("PART") their data are good. However, my `gridAsmPart` only shows one row with the word `(Collection)` on column `PART`. Any help will be appreciated.

```
  public void LoadData()
    {
       var asm = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ASM", dB.connectionString);
       var part = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM PART", dB.connectionString);

       var ds = new DataSet();

        asm.Fill(ds, "ASM");
        part.Fill(ds, "PART");

        DataRelation data_relation = new DataRelation(
            "ASM_PART",
            ds.Tables["ASM"].Columns["PART"],
            ds.Tables["PART"].Columns["PART"]);
        ds.Relations.Add(data_relation);

        gridAsmPart.DataSource = ds;
    }
```

Edit 1: It seems that if I use the old DataGrid, it works.

Comment: High level, create a BindingSource, set the DataSource to the DataSet and the DataMember to the master DataTable from the DataSet. For details, they are shown in another DataGridView which requires a second BindingSource, DataSource is the first BindingSource and the DataMember is the first relation, index 0.  Then using each BindingSource for each DataGridView. Then to get at data e.g. the current row cast the Current property of the BindingSource to a DataRow followed by using Field<type>("columnName") to get the data. Of course the other way is shown by @JohnG

Comment: @KarenPayne, thanks.  You are correct 2 DataGridViews must be used.  The depreciated DataGrid allows Master and Details can be on a single grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well… on the line of code… `gridAsmPart.DataSource = ds;` … `ds` is a `DataSet` and when you assign a `DataSet` to the grid as a `DataSource`, then you also need to specify “which” table in the `DataSet` the grid should display. That is what the grids `DataMember` is for.

Have you tried to set the grids `DataMember` property to something like…?

```
gridAsmPart.DataSource = ds;
gridAsmPart.DataMember = “ASM”;
```

Or if you want the “Part” table to display….

```
gridAsmPart.DataSource = ds;
gridAsmPart.DataMember = “PART”;
```

Comment: Thanks, @JohnG. I thought it was possible to put 2 data tables into a single DataGridView as we can with (the old) DataGrid but it it is not.